# Customize Magento template

Tags: php, magento

I've installed some theme, which has header logo defined in `header.phtml` like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" />
```

I don't really want to alter this template, also in that .phtml file it says not to edit it. How can I override this `getLogoSrc` most efficiently?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  To insert a path to an image?

Comment: @Jonathan Day: The template comes with logo, I want to change/override the logo.

Comment: Fair enough.  See my answer below. That will cater for GIF, JPG or PNG file format.  FYI, it is accepted practice to edit the theme phtml files, in fact you will need to do that to make any significant changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the web admin, go to System>Configuration>Design and scroll down to Header>Logo Image Src. Insert the filename that you have saved in `/skin/frontend/default/new_theme/images/` and click Save.

Comment: ah, how could I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael - don't worry, there are a million different configuration options to get lost in!!  FYI, Stack Overflower Alan Storm has a neat extension for finding them: http://alanstorm.com/magento_configuration_search

Answer (score 0):

Go to your template's images folder e.g.: `/skin/frontend/default/new_theme/images/`

and replace the logo image in that folder with your new Logo

Comment: In the skin, the image is in .gif format, my logo is in .png, I know I can rename it or even hard code template, but I want to know the proper way of how/where to redefine `logo_src` var without changing template code. So again, not looking for quick solution.